# Characteristics and additional conditions for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I need to solve such a DE:
$$(1+x^2)u_x+u_y=0$$
And then I need to draw its characteristics. The second part of the task says:

Write three additional conditions such that this equation:

1. Has one solution
2. Has infinitely many solutions
3. Has none solutions.

My idea:

Let's use the fact, that the characteristics satisfy such a DE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$. So the characteristics are such lines: $y=arctan(x)+C$.

Now I say that the solution is constant on the characteritics, because $\frac{d}{dx}u(x,arctan(x)+C)=u_x+\frac{1}{1+x^2}u_y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}((1+x^2)u_x+u_y)=0$. So the solution is $f(C)=f(y-arctan(x))$.

But I don't know how to continue? How to find the conditions?

Answer (score 0):

1. If the additional condition is $u(0,y)=f(y)$, then the solution $u(x,y)=f(y-\arctan(x))$ is unique;
2. If the additional condition is $u(x,\arctan(x))=0$, then $u(x,y)=g(y-\arctan(x))$ is a solution for any differentiable function $g$ such that $g(0)=0$;
3. If the additional condition is $u(x,\arctan(x))=h(x)$, where $h$ is a nonconstant function, then there is no solution.